# How to populate Selected column in ItemSeclector with default values in Ext-JS

Tags: javascript, extjs, itemselector

I am using ItemSelector in Ext.ux.form.  I need to populate the Selected column with some default values.  I can populate the Available column correctly but when I try to set the store of toField to the default values, it ends up in the Available column.  Following is the code snippet.  Could anyone please help me out?

```
                                 var data = [{"name":"abcd"}];

                                 var ds = SailPoint.Store.createStore({
                                    url: CONTEXT_PATH + '/define/applications/discoverServers.json',
                                    fields: ['name','value'],
                                    autoLoad: true,
                                    baseParams: {domain : domain},
                                    listeners: {
                                                load: function() {
                                                alert('store loaded');
                                            }
                                        }
                                });

                                var itemselectorField = new Ext.Panel({
                                    title: 'Select Servers',
                                    width: 700,
                                    id:'selectServerId',
                                    bodyPadding: 10,
                                    height: 300,
                                    renderTo: 'itemselector',
                                    layout: 'fit',
                                    items:[{
                                        xtype: 'itemselector',
                                        name: 'itemselector',
                                        id: 'itemselectorField',
                                        anchor: '100%',
                                        imagePath: '../images/extjs-ux/',
                                        store: ds,
                                        displayField: 'name',
                                        valueField: 'name',
                                        allowBlank: false,                                          
                                        msgTarget: 'side',
                                        fromTitle: 'Available',
                                        toTitle: 'Selected',
                                        listeners: {
                                            afterrender: function() {
                                                    Ext.getCmp('itemselectorField').toField.store.loadData(data);
                                                    Ext.getCmp('selectServerId').doLayout();
                                                    alert("After Render");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the setValue method of your itemselector field.
Your listeners object should look like this:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(field) { //Add the field argument to the afterrender
        var a = []; // The setValue method receives an Array
        for(var key in data) {
            a.push(data[key].name);
        }
        field.setValue(a);
    }
}
```

A fiddle so you can take a look: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gue